# Is it allowed to use Keruga as a Companion when using a split card with CMC >= 3?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

The situation: I am playing MTGO and I have a deck with Keruga, the Macrosage in my sideboard and Response // Resurgence in my main deck.

Keruga, the Macrosage states the following, emphases mine:

> Companion — **Your starting deck contains only cards with converted mana
>   cost 3 or greater and land cards.** (If this card is your chosen
>   companion, you may cast it once from outside the game.)
>
> When Keruga, the Macrosage enters the battlefield, draw a card for
>   each other permanent you control with converted mana cost 3 or
>   greater.

The problem: MTGO shows that Keruga, the Macrosage is not a valid Companion once Response // Resurgence is included in my deck, a card with a CMC of 7.

Referencing both rules of split cards:

> 708.4. In every zone except the stack, the characteristics of a split card are those of its two halves combined. This is a change from
>   previous rules.
>
> 708.4b The mana cost of a split card is the combined mana costs of its two halves. A split card’s colors and converted mana cost are
>   determined from its combined mana cost. An effect that refers
>   specifically to the symbols in a split card’s mana cost sees the
>   separate symbols rather than the whole mana cost.

So it should be allowed to cast Keruga, the Macrosage as a companion in this case, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are entirely right, there is no reason that Response // Resurgence should stop you from having Keruga as a companion. Seems like a bug in MTGO to me.